# How to get rid of word 'Timestamp' and tuple while appending datetime from csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, datetime

I am trying to make a list of datetime from csv to match my result with detected LSTM test.

Whenever I use loop to extract datetime and value I always get non string word 'Timestamp' with datetime.

my code is here:

```py
m = [ 49,  50] #index of results which I have to match with datetime to extract all information

result_details = []
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    if index in m:
        result_details.append([rows[0],
                                rows[1]])
print(result_details)
```

My csv:

```
           datetimeAt             value
0       2021-12-01 00:00:00       0.000
5       2021-12-01 01:00:00       0.000
10      2021-12-01 02:00:00       0.000
15      2021-12-01 03:00:00       0.000
20      2021-12-01 04:00:00       0.000
...             ...                ...
1149    2021-12-10 13:00:00       2.756
1154    2021-12-10 14:00:00       1.297
1159    2021-12-10 15:00:00       1.503
1164    2021-12-10 16:00:00       1.417
1169    2021-12-10 17:00:00       0.084
```

Whenever I append I get out put like this :

```
[[Timestamp('2021-12-01 10:00:00'), 13.266044921875], 
[Timestamp('2021-12-01 09:00:00'), 9.5365595703125]]
```

How do I get output like below? (only date and value without tuple, string and words)

```
[2021-12-01 10:00:00, 13.266044921875], 
[2021-12-01 09:00:00, 9.5365595703125]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the 'datetimeAt' column as `timestamp` data-type.
You can cast the type to string and then it would work, something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

m = [49, 50, 60] #index of results which I have to match with datetime to extract all information
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='h')

data = np.random.random(size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetimeAt': days, 'value': data})

result_details = []
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    if index in m:
        result_details.append([str(rows[0]),
                                rows[1]])
print(result_details)
```

**Note:** You should avoid `for loops` when dealing with dataframes as much as possible, because if you got a bit table then it can get slow. Instead, you can use vectorized methods which is very efficient, e.g.:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

m = [49, 50] #index of results which I have to match with datetime to extract all information
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='h')

data = np.random.random(size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetimeAt': days, 'value': data})

df['datetimeAt'] = df['datetimeAt'].astype(str)
result_details = df.loc[m,:].values.tolist()
print(result_details)
```

output:

```py
[['2021-12-18 07:11:58.086250', 0.3699851325750202], 
['2021-12-18 08:11:58.086250', 0.6787871001450321]]
```

**EDIT:** Test it with

```
pandas                    1.3.5
pandas                    0.23.4  
python 3.7 & 3.9
```

Comment: Hi Dariyoush, Thank you for the reply. Let me check it.

Comment: sure, let me know if you ran into a problem.

Comment: Still I am getting this error, Is it the version problem? KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Int64Index([177, 178, 198, 200, 201], dtype='int64')

Comment: I tried to use second one.

Comment: Yes, probably your pandas is older than mine. If you can, update your pandas.

Comment: I am using google Colab, let me upgrade it.

Comment: Didn't work, I am still searching.

Comment: @giblegarcham I updated the second version of the code(vectorized one) I am guessing it was because of `.loc[]` and I tested with the old and the newest pandas version and It works. if it does not for you, please post the error in the comment section, so, maybe others can help you. good luck. :)

Comment: i need to do a similar thing, but my data frame is having many fields and some of those fields are datetime- which inturn gives me the TimeStamp(['2022-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss]') when it made into tuples for inserting into sql. how do i address this? thanks for your help